# Onde fica a lista de CSS que o wordpress carrega?

Tags: wordpress

Meu site wordpress está carregando alguns CSS que não servem pra nada e preciso excluir algumas das entradas, ex:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='int-banner-css-css' href='http://fortram.info/rafa/wp-content/plugins/mega-addons-for-visual-composer/render/../css/int_banner-2.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Porém, não sei em que arquivo / local do código é criada essa linha pra que eu possa excluir.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Isso pode variar um pouco de tema para tema, mas normalmente estão no Header. Vc pode acessar pelo painel do Admin na opção Aparência. Em último caso pode ir nas pastas localizar o .css e deixa-lo vazio (faça um bkp de segurança e apague o conteúdo do .css), só renomear o arquivo não é legal pq a requisição vai falhar e dar erro no console etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então os métodos que eu conheço e sempre alterei os estilos nos meus sites, são os seguintes:

1. Vá em: **aparência > editor de temas > "os arquivos estão à direita".**
2. Outra forma de alterar o css/estilo do site em wordpress é direto pelo
   campo "personalizar":

**personalizar > Custom CSS/JS(pode variar de nome) > "só alterar o que precisa, utilizando por nome de classes e divs".**

Uma das duas respostas pode te ajudar.

Comment: Não cumprimente e não agradeça nas publicações.